# Azure Logic Apps HTTP Trigger auth issue

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I'm running a HTTP as trigger to hit an endpoint which takes in username and parameters and issues an Access Token for use with future requests. Below is my HTTP, which is giving me: {"error_code":"103","error_message":"Username or Password cannot be empty"}

I even tried changing the Authentication to Basic and entered username and password in the credentials sections, still same error.

I debuged this, by pinging the URI using postman with POST request, passing credentials and it worked and I received the Access token.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your body content perhaps should be inside the URI

```
https://.....API/Login?username=XXXX&password=YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it but passing creds in the body,

{
 "username":"xxx",
 "password":"yyy"
}